# Array of functions, evaluation in plot

Tags: evaluation

I would like to create two arrays of functions `yfunc[[i]]` and `tfunc[[i]]`, with each entry of those functions being a function depending on t, that is to say

```
yfunc={yfunc[[1]][t],yfunc[[2]][t],...}
```

and the same for `tfunc`. Then I would also like to plot members of these array with `ParametricPlot` in pairs, e.g.

```
ParametricPlot[{yfunc[[i]][t],tfunc[[i]][t]},{t,0,1}]
```

This code works:

```
yfunc[t_?NumericQ, i_?IntegerQ] := i*t;
tfunc[t_?NumericQ, i_?IntegerQ] := 2 i*t;
comp[i_] := {tfunc[t, i], yfunc[t, i]};
Show[ParametricPlot[comp[1], {t, 0, 1}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

But another try of creating this function array fails:

```
yfunc[t_?NumericQ] := Table[i*t, {i, 1, 100}]
tfunc[t_?NumericQ] := Table[2 i*t, {i, 1, 100}];
comp[i_?IntegerQ] := {tfunc[[i]][t], yfunc[[i]][t]};
Show[ParametricPlot[comp[1], {t, 0, 1}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I guess in this case it is a problem with the evaluation. What would be the correct way to do it in the second way?

Thanks!

Comment: Your patterns do not match; first argument is a real, second is an integer.

Comment: Yes this works fine. Thanks! This resolved the first case. I mixed up t and i. Edited the post to correct this.

Comment: in the first example, you probably meant `comp[i_] := {tfunc[t, i], yfunc[t, i]}` (which works fine). Similarly for the second example: `comp[i_] := {tfunc[t][[i]], yfunc[t][[i]]}` works.

Comment: The problem with using `comp[i_] := {tfunc[t][[i]], yfunc[t][[i]]}` is that first every function in the vector gets evaluated only to choose one value of interest in the end. This is of course no problem in the toy model i*t, but takes more time with longer arrays and more complicated functions.

Comment: malumno, even with the toy example, it is quite slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with not using `tfunc[t][[i]]` and trying as you do to call `tfunc[[i]][t]` is that tfunc is not a list and cannot be indexed. The result of calling `tfunc[t]` is a list, which can be indexed.
If you want to use a list of functions, you can use anonymous functions:

```
yfunc = Table[With[{i = i}, Function[t, i*t]], {i, 1, 100}];
tfunc = Table[With[{i = i}, Function[t, 2 i*t]], {i, 1, 100}];

comp[i_?IntegerQ, t_] := {tfunc[[i]][t], yfunc[[i]][t]};
Show[ParametricPlot[comp[1, t], {t, 0, 1}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Note that since `Function` has attribute `HoldAll`, `With[{i=i},...]` is used to inject the value of `i` into the expression. If you don't do this it wont work as: `Table[Function[t,i],{i,2}]` evalutes to `{Function[t,i],Function[t,i]}`.